# What kind of curve can be the branch cut of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can be unit circle $|z| = 1 $ be the branch cut of a function?

Answer (score 1):

Branch cut is something one makes within a domain (=open connected set) to obtain a single-valued function within the rest of the domain. For example, the upper semi-circle is a branch cut for $f(z) = \sqrt{1-z^2}$, meaning that  the complement of this semicircle is a domain in which $f$ admits a single-valued branch.

But cutting along the entire circle *disconnects* the plane. You no longer have a single domain in which to define $f$, but rather two domains with no relation to each other. This is like curing a headache with an axe.

So, I would not  refer to this process (removing the unit circle from the plane) as making a  branch cut. It's more like you picked two, much smaller, subdomains, and decided to study the function separately in each of them.

Comment: But still the question in the general case is not answered.